# React Web App with two APIs, find matching names and return results

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have two APIs stored in mongoDB that are displayed in two tables in a React based webpage, one for teams and one for players. I want to create a function where I click on the team name from the left table and it checks to see if there are any players that belong to that team on the right table. The two APIs aren't directly connected but I want to check if the name matches then it displays results based on the name. Any assistance would be appreciated, I am trying to work with the best way to solve this problem. My screenshots of the app, code snippets and the APIs are below
**Teams API**

```
[
   {
      "_id":"62e9a16df4459d1c5fa1e876",
      "team_name":"Los Angeles Rams"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62e9a178f4459d1c5fa1e877",
      "team_name":"San Francisco 49ers"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62e9a17ff4459d1c5fa1e878",
      "team_name":"Green Bay Packers"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62eafc32a50f5d0a4c87ad59",
      "team_name":"Seattle Seahawks"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62ec18ef44f3c6825fc8afa5",
      "team_name":"Baltimore Ravens"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62ec19967b7d859026f9f08f",
      "team_name":"New England Patriots"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62ec219089471b71043592f6",
      "team_name":"Chicago Bears"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62f2bcec617ec02092113f1d",
      "team_name":"Buffalo Bills"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62f2bcf5617ec02092113f1e",
      "team_name":"Miami Dolphins"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62f2bcfd617ec02092113f1f",
      "team_name":"New York Jets"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62f2c09d617ec02092113f22",
      "team_name":"San Jose Earthquakes"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62f696d18ead5f49211fa76a",
      "team_name":"New York Giants"
   }
]
```

**Players API**

```
[
   {
      "_id":"62f2bd43617ec02092113f20",
      "age":"35",
      "name":"Chase Daniel",
      "position":"QB",
      "ranking":"14",
      "team":"Los Angeles Rams"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62f2bd91617ec02092113f21",
      "age":"23",
      "name":"Leddie Brwon",
      "position":"RB",
      "ranking":"35",
      "team":"Los Angeles Rams"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62f2c0c2617ec02092113f23",
      "age":"21",
      "name":"Joe Brown",
      "position":"TE",
      "ranking":"5",
      "team":"San Jose Earthquakes"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62f696ea8ead5f49211fa76b",
      "age":"25",
      "name":"Daniel Jones",
      "position":"QB",
      "ranking":"8",
      "team":"New York Giants"
   },
   {
      "_id":"62f697098ead5f49211fa76c",
      "age":"21",
      "name":"Evan Neal",
      "position":"OT",
      "ranking":"73",
      "team":"New York Giants"
   }
]
```

**React Tables**

```
<Table bordered hover>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Team Name</th>
        </tr>    
    </thead>
    {teams && teams.map((item, index) => (
        <tbody key={index}>
            <tr>
                <td>{index+1}</td>
                <td onClick={/*Function goes here*/}>{item.team_name}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        ))
    }
</Table>

<Table bordered hover>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Ranking</th>
            <th>Team</th>
        </tr>    
    </thead>
    {players && players.map((item, index) => (
        <tbody key={index}>
            <tr>
                <td>{index+1}</td>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.age}</td>
                <td>{item.position}</td>
                <td>{item.ranking}</td>
                <td>{item.team}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        ))
    }
</Table>
```

**Web App**
[image: Two Tables]

Essentially I want to create a function where if `{teams.item.team_name} == {players.item.team}` then it will return all of the players that belong to that team.

Comment: Does it work after reloading the page? Also this sounds like it will need a state manager like Redux or Context.

Comment: Nvm Redux or Context would be overkill for this. React useState would work. I'm a bit of a rookie but this isnt too hard. Just give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

So looking more closely at your app, I think you need to learn a bit more about React and state management in general. There are several ways to go about this. The simplest would be with React useState, and I'd recommend YouTube for several awesome tutorials.

First, your API's should be linked. If you end up using a backend, that will affect your API format. If not, you still need to match you players with your team by having an extra matching name/id or a reference to the opposite object.

You'll `import {useState} from React` at the top.

Then declare something like `const [team, setTeam] = useState()`

In your players table element, you'll end up passing a prop like this `<table team={team} ...>`

In your onClick you'll reference some kind of handleSubmit function you made at the top where you `setTeam`. So,

```
const handleClick = (id) =>
  ...
  setTeam(team.findByID(id)) // or something similar
  ...
```

These aren't exact answers but should put you in the right direction. Your question doesn't have a quick and easy code fix. I'd really recommend a couple React useState tutorials. You're app would be the perfect practice for it.